# execvp error on file –np on MPI

Tags: mpi

When I try to run c file using this command `mpirun –np 2 ./ hellow`
it returns `[proxy:0:0@suganthan-VirtualBox] HYDU_create_process (utils/launch/launch.c:74): execvp error on file ./ (Permission denied)`.
I could not solve this error. could anyone suggest any way to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the space between `./` and `hellow`.